# Problem with alertView clickedButtonAtIndex: crashing when i mention variables. Alternative?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uialertview

I have an NSString called locationForURL1. I tracked it through my code leading into the UITextView and it didn't change at any point. I put an NSLog right before the UIAlertView's 'show' line, and even there locationForURL1 was equal to what it's supposed to be equal to - a URL.

Then the user clicks a button in the alertview and it goes straight into the clickedButtonAtIndex: part.

Here's the code from there:

```
-(void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    NSLog(@"location for url1b %@", locationForURL1);
    if ((alertView.tag <= 3) && (alertView.tag >= 1)) {
        if (buttonIndex == 1) {
            NSLog(@"location for url1 %@", locationForURL1);
```

It doesn't even make it to the 2nd NSLog, it crashes at the first. I've replaced these NSLogs with ones simply saying 'test' so i know it's only happening because of that.

I'm unsure how to solve this problem though? Just the mention of locationForURL1 is crashing it suddenly.

Are there any alternatives to UIAlertView, maybe an open source project to make something similar but better? It's seems very touch and go, from past experience.

Comment: Probably locationForURL1 was released earlier at some point. Are you retaining the string?

Comment: It would be a mistake to blame the crash on UIAlertView. In my experience it is always my fault (in fact your bug may be my fault, in which case I apologise). I agree with Marco, check your memory management of locationForURL1.

Comment: @Marco Mustapic  this is not probably, this is 100% for sure =)

Comment: Yes, it's set to @property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *locationForURL1;

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the NSString is an ivar...is your accessor set to nonatomic? Are you calling the setter? (You should...for both)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should do `self.locationForURL1=aURL` instead of `locationForURL1=aURL` somewhere else. UIAlertView has nothing to do with the crash.

Comment: Just tried that. Makes no difference, still crashes at the same point.

Comment: Add NSZombieEnabled environment variable set to YES in Xcode's executable inspector. That should help you find the over-released object.

Comment: This is what i get:  `*** -[CFString respondsToSelector:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x479a250` What does that mean?

Comment: That means you had released an NSString object located at the address and then sent it a message. Try to track it down in gdb. My guess it's locationForURL1 ivar.